# Using Jinja2 (flask) to loop through a bootstrap accordian

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-4

I am using an accordian, with the default as collapsed. When I run my program everything is collapsed, so ok on that part. However, when I try to click one one and show its contents it only un-collapses the first accordian item.

Here is my code:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for dict_item in intel %}
        <div id="accordion" role="tablist">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  {{ dict_item['name']}} -- {{ dict_item['date'] }}
                </a>
              </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
              <div class="card-body">
              My Stuff in here
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I image it has to do with the id/classes in the html but I am more of a backend guy so I am not an html wizard.

Also, I am using v4 of bootstrap.

Comment: my first thought is valid HTML means each "id" is unique... you can use a jinja loop counter http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#loop-controls to make each ID in your model unique (e.g. `<div id="accordion-{{ loop.index }}"`)... possibly the reason

Comment: Yes, that works. I tried to `enumerate` the list but it doesn't look like jinja2 supports `enumerate`, I just replaced all the instances of "One" with `{{ loop.index }}`

Comment: Great, glad that was it! You can pass any python function to your Jinja template, but they tend to have the builtins and filters to handle most common needs