# Bootstrap accordian in a for loop jinja2

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap accordian element in a for loop in jinja template. The code is as follows:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    {% for article in articles %}
        <div class="accordion-item">
        <h2 class="accordion-header" id="{{article['Id']}}">
            <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            {{article['Job Title']}}
            </button>
        </h2>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-body">
            {{article['Description']}}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

When I am trying to open any one of the accordian-item, it is opening only the first item. Any way to rectify this? I already tried the approach in the question:

[Using Jinja2 (flask) to loop through a bootstrap accordian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45884780/using-jinja2-flask-to-loop-through-a-bootstrap-accordian)

Bu it is not working. Data is formatted as below:

```
({'Id': 12941, 'Discipline': '0 Computational Science ', 'Job Title': 'High-performance Computing', 'Description': 'Some text here'})
```

EDIT: Basically articles are coming from flask backend and I need to render each of the article in a accordian type structure. I copied the code from the example 1 of the page: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

Comment: Please make a little bit more clear. What is coming in `articles`? What you are trying to do, with example? Such things in question. This will make helper easy to understand your goal.

Comment: So, articles is coming from a flask backend. I didn't it was relevant because data is not the problem, rendering it is.

Comment: Not asking from where, asking what is there? Which datatype, probably `dictionary`? Any example data would also be great to understand clearly!

Comment: It is a dictionary containing text for both article['Job Title'] and article['Description'] contain text to be rendered. articles is a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
{% for article in articles %}
    <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="Arr{{article['Id']}}">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#Arr{{article['Id']}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Arr{{article['Id']}}">
        {{article['Job Title']}}
        </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="Arr{{article['Id']}}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
        {{article['Description']}}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The `data-bs-toggle` should always be equal to the target accordion ID. So from my code above, `{{article['Id']}}` would be the unique ID for Bootstrap to identify each accordion element.
Also from your code, the first seems to be the only opened because all `.accordion-collapse` has same ID.
**NOTE:** The ID attribute should be unique in the whole of your page. No two elements should have same ID.
[HTML ID on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp)

**EDIT:** Added `Arr` to the IDs, since numbers isn't a valid HTML ID.

Comment: I tried this. Now none of the elements are opening.

Comment: Inspect your element and see if they have unique IDs. You can Inspect elements by right clicking on the element and clicking on 'Inspect'

Comment: I am getting error "#12941 is not a valid selector"

Comment: Check the updated code. Sorry for the error on my end, numbers are not accepted as valid HTML IDs. Added "Arr" to the ID from the server to make it unique and acceptable.